# wordpress: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_internal_encoding()

Tags: wordpress, plugins, error-handling

I have just installed equifax-credit-check plugin in my wordpress site.Now this error displayed

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_internal_encoding() in /home/uplogictecz/public_html/demo/reportlink/wp-content/plugins/equifax-credit-check/vendor/danielstjules/stringy/src/Stringy.php:58 Stack trace: #0 /home/uplogictecz/public_html/demo/reportlink/wp-content/plugins/equifax-credit-check/vendor/danielstjules/stringy/src/Create.php(17): Stringy\Stringy->__construct('/reportlink/das...', NULL) #1 /home/uplogictecz/public_html/demo/reportlink/wp-content/plugins/equifax-credit-check/class/App.php(179): Stringy\create('/reportlink/das...') #2 /home/uplogictecz/public_html/demo/reportlink/wp-content/plugins/equifax-credit-check/class/PluginCore.php(300): Baerr\App\App::is_dashboard() #3 /home/uplogictecz/public_html/demo/reportlink/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(298): Baerr\App\PluginCore->dashboard_access_control('') #4 /home/uplogictecz/public_html/demo/reportlink/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(323): WP_Hook->apply_filters(false, Array) #5 /home/uplogictecz/public_html/demo/reportlink/wp-includes/pl in /home/uplogictecz/public_html/demo/reportlink/wp-content/plugins/equifax-credit-check/vendor/danielstjules/stringy/src/Stringy.php on line 58
```

In my   `/home/uplogictecz/public_html/demo/reportlink/wp-content/plugins/equifax-credit-check/vendor/danielstjules/stringy/src/Stringy.php on line 58`

Line function is

```
    public function __construct($str = '', $encoding = null)
{
    if (is_array($str)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(
            'Passed value cannot be an array'
        );
    } elseif (is_object($str) && !method_exists($str, '__toString')) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException(
            'Passed object must have a __toString method'
        );
    }

    $this->str = (string) $str;
    $this->encoding = $encoding ?: \mb_internal_encoding();
}
```

This line is `$this->encoding = $encoding ?: \mb_internal_encoding();  no 58.`

How to fix this issue ?.Kindly check it.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP environment is missing MBSTRING extension. It is normal, as mbstring is not built-in default extension in some PHP installations. You can install it if you have an access to your server:

For PHP 5.* and Debian

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
```

For PHP 5.* and Fedora

```
yum install php-mbstring
```

For PHP 7.0, use

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
```

And of course, if you don't have server access, you need to ask your hosting provider to enable this extension for your website server.